# How to improve file reading speed?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I read the data slice from a large file. A 400Mb picture took 4 seconds. It only takes 1 second for the disk to read this file. The program does very little computation. How to improve speed?

```py
from opentile import OpenTile
import time
import traceback
import os
os.environ.setdefault('TURBOJPEG', 'C:/lib/')
try:
    tiler = OpenTile.open('svs800.svs')
except:
    traceback.print_exc()

s=tiler.get_level(0)
tile_size=str(s.tiled_size).split("x")

time1=time.time()

from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool

def get_data(s):
    # This function reads a piece of binary data from a certain position of the image 
    # and then adds the header data
    return tiler.get_tile(0,0,0, (s[0], s[1]))
pool = ThreadPool(5)
y = pool.map(get_data, [(i,j) for i in range(int(tile_size[0])) for j in range(int(tile_size[1]))])

print("tiles",len(y))
time2=time.time()
print(time2)
```

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: You are not using multiple processes. You are using multiple threads. If *get_data()* is CPU-intensive then this is not an ideal strategy

Comment: If what limits you is the disk speed, and you need very little treatment time for the data afterwards, trying to read multiple files simultaneously won't improve things. But I really don't understand from your current description what your situation actually is.

Comment: One way would be to divide the number of lines by the number of cores available on your machine - for example if you have 100 million lines in your text file and 4 cores, each core would take care of 25 million lines - core 1 starting at 0 going to 24999999, core 2 starting at 25000000 going to 49999999 etc... This effectively divides the time processing time by ammount cores you have. If it took 10 seconds, it would take 2.5 with 4 cores

Comment: What are your tile_size values? I have a 563MB SVS file with dimensions of 183x114. On my machine (sequential processing) it takes 0.0064s to open the file and 0.5871s to get the tile data - i.e., 20,862 calls to get_tile. Either your file dimensions are significantly higher than this example or you just have a slow computer

Comment: What's a 400 metre file?

Comment: @MarkSetchell It's a very long file

Comment: @Stuart Can you share the code?

Comment: You should look into [Memory-mapped file support](https://docs.python.org/3/library/mmap.html#module-mmap).

Answer (score 1):

Simple sequential approach:

```
from opentile import OpenTile
import os
import time

def timer(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        start = time.perf_counter()
        result = func(*args, **kwargs)
        end = time.perf_counter()
        print(f'{func.__name__} {end-start:.4f}s')
        return result
    return wrapper

os.environ.setdefault('TURBOJPEG', '/opt/libjpeg-turbo')

@timer
def open_svs(filename):
    return OpenTile.open(filename)

@timer
def get_data(tiler, x, y):
    return [tiler.get_tile(0, 0, 0, (x_, y_)) for x_ in range(x) for y_ in range(y)]

tiler = open_svs('18959.svs')

x, y = map(int, str(tiler.get_level(0).tiled_size).split('x'))

data = get_data(tiler, x, y)

assert len(data) == x * y
```

**Output:**

```
open_svs 0.0082s
get_data 0.5843s
```

**Note:**

```
x, y values for this file are 183, 114 respectively. The file size is 563,271,749 bytes
```

Comment: It seems that my computer is too slow